# Get Text of Linked Document

Tags: c#, api, enterprise-architect

I would like to get a string which contains the formatted text of a linked document (the file linked to an Artifact).

Is it possible using EA API (C#)?

Comment: It should be noted that in the case of a "linked document," the document is stored in the EA database, it's not actually a link to an external file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the internal "linked document" then you can use `EA.Element.GetLinkedDocument()`, which will return you the RTF string.

If you mean an external file linked to your element then you'll need to open it yourself in your code based on the path.
Check `EA.Element.Files`

Comment: As Geert notes, GetLinkedDocument() returns the RTF data, which is in text format but RTF-encoded. To convert to plain text, HTML or Sparx' internal markup format, look at Repository.GetFormatFromField(). Not sure what that will do with things like embedded images in the RTF data, but it should at least allow you to get the text out.

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks a lot. I try to use the method you suggest but still getting the formatted text. Any ideas? `string text= Repository.GetFormatFromField("TXT", element.GetLinkedDocument());`

Comment: I would use some kind of standard RTF library to interpret the RTF code and get the plain text.

Comment: I believe you need to do a two-step: first convert to Sparx' markup using Repository.GetFieldFromFormat(), then convert that to plain text as I mentioned above. So you'll end up with something like `string text = Repository.GetFormatFromField("TXT", Repository.GetFieldFromFormat("RTF", element.GetLinkedDocument()));` But for anything more than very simple documents, you are indeed better off with a dedicated RTF library.

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks a lot! the code you added converts the RTF to simple text. One more thing: the linked document text is formatted with headings. When I convert it to TXT, the headings are replaced with Normal text. Is it possible to roll it back? (I would like to insert this text to a Word document, using the InsertText() API)

Comment: There's an easy way to add the RTF part directly into a word document, without having to convert it. Best google for something like "insert RTF in word document with API"